# listen() maximum queue size per Windows version

Tags: windows, winsock

The Winsock function listen(socket, backlog) has a parameter to specify the size of the queue for pending connections. The program should pass SOMAXCONN to set the queue to its maximum size.

Question: What is the maximum queue size for each Windows version: 2000, XP, Vista, 7?

Thanks!

Reference: [listen() on MSDN Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)

Comment: Reasons for asking this question: I designed a web server and Windows was dropping a few requests even if server answers as fast as possible. This is because modern web browsers fetch more than 5 resources at a time and SOMAXCONN constant was hard coded to 5 in the original WinSock2 header. Calling listen() in server with a queue size larger than 5 solved the issue. I wanted to determine potential risk of every Windows versions.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

What do you hope to achieve once you know the answer to this?

There are many ways to improve the performance of connection acceptance, you should focus on that and not what the actual number of queued connections can be.

The listen backlog should simply accommodate short term discrepancies between the rate at which the server software can accept new connections and the rate at which these new connections are arriving. You should strive to ensure that your server can accept new connections at a suitable rate, ideally by using `AcceptEx()` with IOCP for overlapped accept calls and posting a suitable number of overlapped accepts when your server starts and then topping these up as connections are established.

I talk about this kind of thing on my blog, [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/12/one-million-tcp-connections.html) and [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/how-to-support-10000-or-more-concurrent-tcp-connections---part-2---perf-tests-from-day-0.html).

Comment: WinSock2 header file defined SOMAXCONN to 5. So the queue size was large enough to accept only five clients! My problem is simple: modern web browsers send more than five simultaneous requests to load a web page to get all images at the same time. The result? Some calls fail and the page contains random unavailable images. I want to serve modern web browsers and know how many clients could request a page at the same time. Thanks for your great blog!

Comment: Where did you get your copy of the winsock header, SOMAXCONN is defined as 0x7fffffff in mine. I've run tests with 1000s of concurrent connections per second, using a listen backlog of around 100 and overlapped I/O and AcceptEx. The problem you are having shouldn't occur.

Comment: I have an original WinSock2 header. Help file from Microsoft clearly states: backlog is currently limited (silently) to 5. Illegal values (less than 1 or greater than 5) are replaced by the nearest legal value... This was true fifteen years ago!

Comment: Ok, well it's not true now. Get an up to date compiler and/or platform SDK.

Comment: By the way... Even if SOMAXCONN were 5 on modern operating systems and even if your listen backlog were set to 5, it doesn't mean that you can't accept more than 5 connections, you simply have to accept them quickly...

Comment: I have asked a question very closely related with this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548765/how-to-set-maximum-queue-connection-for-nginx-port-in-windows) .

Answer (score 14):

It was 5 back on NTWS 4.0: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127144

I believe in XP it was also this way, although from XP on it's hard to find anything concrete from Microsoft. (At least for me, that is how I ended up here hoping for an actual answer).

A quick seat-of-the-pants Java test showed that the default for Windows 7 Pro is 50, and the limit is 200. FWIW.

I'm not sure why someone would answer this with an assumption about *why* the question is asked. There are legitimate reasons for knowing the actual answer.

For example, you have software where you may receieve a burst of requests. If the max backlog by the operating system is 5, you may end up refusing connections even if handing them off as quickly as possible. And a backlog of 200 alleviates this. And because of this, you may want to make a OS system requirement to not use an OS that has such a backlog limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The backlog parameter of the listen(socket, backlog) function is limited to `SOMAXCONN`. If set to `SOMAXCONN`, the underlying service provider responsible for the socket will set the backlog to a maximum reasonable value<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)</sup>.

The maximum value on Windows platforms was<sup>[2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/06/01/winsocks-listen-backlog-offers-more-flexibility-in-windows-8/)</sup>:

- Windows Sockets 1 defines `SOMAXCONN = 5`. Winsock 1.1 was part of Windows 95 and Windows NT 3.5.
- Windows Sockets 2 defines `SOMAXCONN = 0x7fffffff` and limits the listen backlog to a large value (typically several hundred or more). Winsock 2.1 was an add-on to Windows 95 and part of Windows 98, Windows NT 4.0 and all subsequent Windows releases.
- Windows 8 includes the "RIO" (Registered IO) extensions for Winsock. These extensions are designed to reduce the latency of network applications<sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock)</sup>. The macro `SOMAXCONN_HINT(N)` can be used to set the backlog to a larger value than possible with `SOMAXCONN`. The backlog value will be N, adjusted to be within the range (200, 65535)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)</sup>.

**Note**:

"When calling the listen() function in a Bluetooth application, it is strongly recommended that a much lower value be used for the backlog parameter (typically 2 to 4), since only a few client connections are accepted. This reduces the system resources that are allocated for use by the listening socket. This same recommendation applies to other network applications that expect only a few client connections."<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)</sup>

**Sources**:

1. [listen function, Winsock2.h documentation, Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen)
2. [Winsock’s Listen() Backlog Offers More Flexibility In Windows 8+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/06/01/winsocks-listen-backlog-offers-more-flexibility-in-windows-8/)
3. [Winsock, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it be 200 on Windows 7, but I don't know if it's tied to the OS or if networking drivers etc. might have an influence.

You can experimentally determine this by listening on a port and making a lot of connections to that port without accepting them until you're done (then see how many you got).

If you take Len's advise and use AcceptEx with IOCP, you can pretty much determine for yourself how large of a backlog you have by calling it in advance on a pool of waiting connections. I've seen this work with as many as 1,600 connections in the pool, but it does seem to have a limit as well.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there is a default of 5 in the async sockets Listen() code for Visual Studio 9.0 (aka 2008).
I found this in c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxsock.h:
    `BOOL Listen(int nConnectionBacklog=5);`

Also documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class?view=vs-2019#listen

Comment: Hi Jon. You mention the default connection backlog size, while I'm interested to know the maximum backlog size, per operating system. BR